# Minifigure overview and Combinator

Tags: minifigures, software

Does anyone know website or program which provides an easy overview over LEGO minifigures and allow me to recombine parts from different minifigures and show me kind of preview picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [noted by J.C. Tchang](https://jc-tchang.philohome.com/model/creamodel.htm#minifig), some options include [leocad](https://www.leocad.org/)'s minifig wizard...

[image: leocad minifig wizard]

... and [bricksmith](https://bricksmith.sourceforge.io/)'s minifig generator:

[image: bricksmith minifig generator]

Comment: I will go with LeoCAD’s Minifig Wizard, although i wish it had some Filtering or Search function